# VHDL simple optimization

Tags: vhdl

I have the following code and I am trying if possible to make it more professional, by using loops for example.

```
ENTITY cc IS
    PORT ( s, x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9    : IN    BIT;
           m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9                                               : OUT   BIT );
END cc;

ARCHITECTURE cc_logic OF cc IS
BEGIN
    m0 <= (NOT(s) XOR x0) XNOR (s OR y0) ;
    m1 <= (NOT(s) XOR x1) XNOR (s OR y1) ;
    m2 <= (NOT(s) XOR x2) XNOR (s OR y2) ;
    m3 <= (NOT(s) XOR x3) XNOR (s OR y3) ;
    m4 <= (NOT(s) XOR x4) XNOR (s OR y4) ;
    m5 <= (NOT(s) XOR x5) XNOR (s OR y5) ;
    m6 <= (NOT(s) XOR x6) XNOR (s OR y6) ;
    m7 <= (NOT(s) XOR x7) XNOR (s OR y7) ;
    m8 <= (NOT(s) XOR x8) XNOR (s OR y8) ;
    m9 <= (NOT(s) XOR x9) XNOR (s OR y9) ;
END cc_logic ;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `standard` package with `bit` also has a `bit_vector`, so if the interface
can be changed to use vector instead of single bits, then the code can be
written for VHDL-2002 as:

```
ENTITY cc IS
    PORT ( s : IN  BIT;
           x : IN  BIT_VECTOR(0 TO 9);
           y : IN  BIT_VECTOR(0 TO 9);
           m : OUT BIT_VECTOR(0 TO 9));
END cc;

ARCHITECTURE cc_logic OF cc IS
BEGIN
  loop_gen : FOR idx IN m'RANGE GENERATE
    m(idx) <= ((NOT s) XOR x(idx)) XNOR (s OR y(idx));
  end generate;
END cc_logic;
```

Note that `NOT(s)`, was changed to `(NOT s)` since assumption is that it is the
intention, and the logical operation when doing outer `XOR` is equivalent.

The architecture may also be written without the generate loop doing:

```
ARCHITECTURE cc_logic OF cc IS
  SIGNAL s_vec : BIT_VECTOR(0 to 9);
BEGIN
  s_vec <= (OTHERS => s);
  m <= ((NOT s_vec) XOR x) XNOR (s_vec OR y);
END cc_logic;
```

And if VHDL-2008 is supported in the used tools, then you can reduce it even
more with:

```
ARCHITECTURE cc_logic OF cc IS
BEGIN
  m <= ((NOT s) XOR x) XNOR (s OR y);
END cc_logic;
```

Finally, you may consider using `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` instead of
`bit` and `bit_vector`, since the additional states in `std_logic` makes
simulation more accurate when having unknown input data.

Comment: For better accuracy in simulation use `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector` which will help you find double-driver errors that a resolved type will mask.

Comment: @Chiggs: For VHDL-2008 it sounds reasonable, but for VHDL-2002 and before then `std_ulogic_vector` and `std_logic_vector` are distinct thus incompatible types, so it will be inconvenient to combine own modules using `std_ulogic_vector` with 3rd party module usually using `std_logic_vector`.  Also, any double-drivers are identified and reported as error by synthesis tools, thus they won't to unnoticed for long.